# Create single installer from multiple projects for single application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

In Visual Studio, I have 2 projects in my solution which are the main project and the tool project.

My single application uses both main project and tool project.

I want to make a single installer for my application.

Comment: can you please share the details of what you have tried so far?

Comment: My application.

https://s15.postimg.org/h7hf0r223/my_application.png

I followed this tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGK0FiUoiJc

However, he didn't show how to deal with multiple projects like mine.

After setup, I double click the shortcut in desktop and the Error occurs.

https://s17.postimg.org/n0o8rv5lb/Error_Shadow_Setup_Project_picture.png

I believe that Error occurs because I didn't include the tool project in the making installer process.

Therefore, I want to know how to add tool project  in the making installer process.

Comment: I have tried to add both projects like this.

https://s24.postimg.org/a9y1dg91h/2output.png

I believe that this is wrong and I get Error after installation too.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by following this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBVyrZuSsQE

but I change "Add Project Outputs" to "Add Folder" (so I add 2 project folder here) in this process.

https://s24.postimg.org/7a7snduyd/Add_folder.png

Then, in the "Application Shortcuts" process, I select the shortcut from main project folder.

Anyway, Thank you for encouraging me to solve this problem

Sincerely

Mr.PePae