# Can i add two or more projects that are separate into one installer with an option to either install one or both

Tags: c#, wpf

I got two project is Visual Studio 2022. They are separate but i need them to be in one installer. So when the user decides to install them, they have the option to install one or both using either a button or a tickbox inside the installer. The info like video etc is not specific for what i need.

Cheers

I looked on youtube for the setup project for vs and on here but for what i needed, its always a single project for a single installer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054247/create-single-installer-from-multiple-projects-for-single-application-in-visual

Comment: this is not working and the links are outdated